# VB.Net Calculate Week Number with DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I have a DateTimePicker : DateTimePicker1
and a TextBox : Textbox3

How may i do when i select a Date since DateTimePicker1 to see the number week of the date ????

Comment: `Calendar.GetWeekOfYear()`   Please read [Ask] and also take the [Tour].  This is far from a well written, well asked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADD

```
Imports System
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Threading
```

AND

```
TextBox4.Text = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTimePicker1.Text, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday)
```